# How does Microsoft Test Manager run automated Generic Tests?

Tags: testing, deployment, microsoft-test-manager

I'm using Microsoft Test Manager and I have linked a test case to a generic test in Visual Studio. A lab environment is configured. When I run the test, the test agent only copies the *.generictest file from the build servers drop location. The proper test application (and some config files) are not copied to the test server. Adding the path of the missing files via test settings (advanced -> deployment) doesn't help, because the path depends on the current server build. So a static link is not really useful.

Is there any other possibility to include the appropriate files?